# Benefits of twin-in/single-out propulsion

Tags: propulsion, marine-engineering

I've seen, in some marine engine project guides, arrangements where you have two medium-speed engines coupled to one propeller through a gearbox instead of one larger engine running that propeller. I've also seen the twin-in/single-out approach done with electric motors in Diesel-electric vessels.

My question is, why do some vessels (assuming twin-screw) use this arrangement instead of two larger prime movers?

Answer (score 2):

Four into two arrangement can help with mid speed fuel economy, but that often isn't enough by itself to justify the complexity. Sometimes, the the general arrangement of things is better. The two engines need not be the same. For instance, near shore in areas with emissions restrictions, one of the engines can be emissions compliant, perhaps running dual fuels with the second being a big, dumb bunker diesel. Or commonly, one is a diesel and the other is a GTE (as is the case with the totally botched Freedom class LCS.)

Military vessels such as the DDG-51 (4 GTEs into 2 shafts) will do this to achieve a high sprint speed as well as an efficient cruise speed using one of the pair. It also gives them redundancy. With turbines, you need a lot of gearing anyway, so the combining gears don't add much to what is needed to gear a GTE down to shaft speed.

Comment: Oh, you can remove and install the smaller pieces a lot easier without having to cut the boat in half. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pw6-82YVIbE , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LgMj5q3tqU

Answer (score 0):

Using two can make low to mid propulsion more efficient with full power available with both.

Otherwise one single could be running out of its efficiency band if the load required is low.

Case in point was when the aerodynamic roofs were added to some trucks the fuel consumption became worse as the combination of the load and throttle position took the engine out of its efficient design point.

As another example, many production processes that require a lot of heat are supplied from multiple boilers say 4 and any 3 out of the 4 are capable. The 4th is spare for maintenance or breakdown.

Comment: But that just begs the question why don't you just use one larger engine if ganging two smaller engines together is more efficient than ganging two larger ones. Unless you are suggesting to just run one engine when you need low power (which wasn't made explicit in your answer).

Comment: @DKNguyen Even power factor control units apply the same concept with several capacitors, of different sizes, being combined in configurations to match the reactive load - check it out, lots of fun calculations…